# Excel Vlookup to loop through values until Value is not 0

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have this data,

Roots data

```
ID Amount
1  *Blank*
1  10
2  20
3  30
```

transactions data

```
ID    BID 
1      ?
2      ?
3      ?
```

I vlookup the ID into a different sheet to find the Amount for a particular ID. Butt its current only displaying the Amount at the first instead of the ID.

I am using: `=vlookup(A2,'Roots data'!F2:G1855,2,FALSE)` at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
=INDEX('Roots data'!$G$2:$G$1855,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Roots data'!$F$2:$F$1855=A2)*('Roots data'!$G$2:$G$1855<>"")*('Roots data'!$G$2:$G$1855<>0),),0))
```

**EDIT**: Formula will now ignore results that are 0 as well as blanks.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this did not work. I have a transactions sheet where I have a deal ID I then look in roots for this Deal ID and if it finds it, then it displays the BID for this Deal ID in Roots.

Comment: @GeorgeH This works for me based on your sample data.  If it's not working for you, then please edit your post to provide sample data that is more representative of your actual data.

Comment: In some cases the BID for a deal ID is 0 and if it is I want it to look at the next instance of the Deal ID in Roots.

Comment: Hi, this has worked. Thank you for your patience and help on this.

Comment: Hi, How can I force the cell to be 0 if an ID cannot be found? at the moment its coming through as N/A.

Comment: Wrap it in [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611): `IFERROR(INDEX('Roots data'!$G$2:$G$1855,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Roots data'!$F$2:$F$1855=A2)*('Roots data'!$G$2:$G$1855<>"")*('Roots data'!$G$2:$G$1855<>0),),0)),0)`